# MVC 5 - raise Bootstrap Modal from Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Coming from WebForms getting my head around some MVC stuff is not quite intuitive and I am struggling to find a way to modal to pop-up from the controller (depending upon the postback result)..

The modal

```
<div id="PopupModal" class="modal fade in out">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button class="close" aria-hidden="true" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="ModalTitle"></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="ModalBody">
                    <h5 id="ModalBodyText"></h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is how I would have raised the event in WebForms

```
Private Sub ModalValidation(Message As String)
        Try
            Dim SB As New StringBuilder
            SB.Append("$(document).ready(function(){")
            SB.Append("$('#PopupModal').modal();")
            SB.Append("var vBody = document.getElementById('ModalBodyText');")
            SB.Append("vBody.innerHTML = '" & Message & "';")
            SB.Append("var vTitle = document.getElementById('ModalTitle');")
            SB.Append("vTitle.innerHTML = 'Validation';")
            SB.Append("vTitle.style.color = 'orange';")
            SB.Append("});")
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "ValidationShowModal", SB.ToString, True)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim vError As New SendError
            vError.MailError(60, PageName, ex)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

How can I raise the same event from the controller?

Thanks

Edit = Big thank you to Vitor Salgado for pointing me in the right direction

Added this to the controller - Index

```
Function Index() As ActionResult
        Dim vPopup As New UploadFilesResult
        If Not Session("PopupMessage") Is Nothing Then
            vPopup.PopupMessage = Session("PopupMessage")
        Else
            vPopup.PopupMessage = "None"
        End If

        ViewData("UploadFilesResult") = vPopup
        Return View("BlueImpMinView")
    End Function
```

Added this to Controller - ActionResult (where the action completed normally)

```
Session("PopupMessage") = "The file was successfully uploaded!"
        Return Redirect("/blueimp/Index#Completed")
```

Added a hidden field to the view

```
 @code
    Dim vPopup As MVPTest.UploadFilesResult = CType(ViewData("UploadFilesResult"), MVPTest.UploadFilesResult)
    Dim vPopupMessage As String = vPopup.PopupMessage
    @Html.TextBox("MessageTB", vPopupMessage, New With {.type = "hidden"})
End Code
```

and the javascript for the modal

```
<script>

window.onload = function () {
    var vType = location.hash;
    var vMessage = document.getElementById('MessageTB').value;
    switch (vType) {
        case '#Completed':
            //run code for completed modal

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#PopupModal').modal();
                var vBody = document.getElementById('ModalBodyText');
                vBody.innerHTML = vMessage;
                var vTitle = document.getElementById('ModalTitle');
                vTitle.innerHTML = 'Success';
                vTitle.style.color = 'green';
            });
            break;
        case '#Error':
            //run code for error modal

            break;
        case '#Validation':
            //run code for validation modal
    }


}


</script>
```

Comment: Why raise it from the controller? Why are you appending script? The controller should affect the view in that way: it should pass any necessary data to the view, then the view should figure out how to display itself (which might involve client side code). Make sure you properly understand the MVC architecture and the roles that the View and Controller play and how they should be interacting.

Comment: Hi Mason - the Controller is where all the data processing is carried out. I understand that ScriptManager is part of WebForms not MVC, I'm just trying to find a way of raising the Modal once the data-processing has completed (or not as the case may be). I have to say I don't yet understand the architecture that well yet, but I only jumped in a few days ago - the only way I learn is jumping in and trying things....

Comment: I would suggest doing the validation in your controller then pass the model (inc. validation) to the view and let the view work it out.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're POSTing data to a controller, then when the View is rendered again, you want to display a modal. Is that right?

Comment: Jamie - can you give me an example? - MarkPSmith - correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In controller code, you could append to your querystring some marker parameter or return a specific cookie, then, in your javascript code, you can identify one of these marker values and show your modal window.

Here some sample code..

The controller

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
    return Redirect("/Home/Register#registered");
}
```

The view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <label>Login</label><br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Login)

    <br />

    <label>Name</label><br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)

    <br />

    <label>Email</label><br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Emai)

    <br />

    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
}

<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function () {
        if (window.location.hash == '#registered') {
            alert('Your modal code here!');
        }
    };

</script>
```

The action Register(POST) is the server side code that will create some marker to your client side code. In the sample, a added a hash value to url. You could return a cookie value or better, add some value to hidden field and read the value from it. In the view, a have simple JS code that executes on page load. The JS search for the hash value and show the modal.

Comment: Vitor - could you show an example of what you mean? I can certainly return a value to, say, a hidden textbox or use a session variable but coming from doing everything in code-behind I'm not sure how to capture the page load event in a view (or even if that can be done)

Comment: That looks like the answer :-) Will try it after lunch then mark it as such. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this that fit within the MVC way of doing things.  Here's what I would do...

If you need the server to decide whether or not to show the modal, but you don't wish to refresh the page, then AJAX is probably what you want.  Use can use jQuery's ajax calls to post data to a controller action, make a decision on the server, then send back a result that your js can use to either show the modal or not.  This way, the page does not need to refresh yet you make a round trip to the server to decide what you need to do.